# spring boot reactor not logging request id contextually

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, spring-webflux, log4j2, project-reactor

I am trying to capture request id and decorate every log message with it. Using log4j2 and webflux.

```
        return Mono.fromCompletionStage(..removed..)
                .build()))
                .map(ExecutionResult::toSpecification)
                .map(stringObjectMap -> new ResponseEntity<>(new ApplicationResponse(requestId,
                         ((Map<String, Object>) stringObjectMap.get("data"))), HttpStatus.OK))
                .doOnEach(logOnNext(
                        res -> logger.info("processing.."))
                )
                .contextWrite(ctx-> ctx.put("REQUEST_ID", requestId));
```

Above code is in a controller. In the pipeline stream, calling a service class as follows:

```
                @Override
                public Mono<SomeDTO> getSomething(final String clientId) {
// I Dont see the request ID for this invocation.
                    return repo.getSomething(clientId)
                                .doOnEach(logOnNext(r -> log.debug("Impl.something::START")));
                }
```

And finally this is the helper class for `logOnNext` from [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.mdc).

```
    public static <T> Consumer<Signal<T>> logOnNext(Consumer<T> logStatement) {
        return signal -> {
            if (!signal.isOnNext()) return;
            Optional<String> request_idMaybe = signal.getContext().getOrEmpty("REQUEST_ID");

            log.info("request id may be {}", request_idMaybe);

            request_idMaybe.ifPresentOrElse(requestId -> {
                try (MDC.MDCCloseable closeable = MDC.putCloseable("REQUEST_ID", requestId)) {
                    logStatement.accept(signal.get());
                }
            }, () -> logStatement.accept(signal.get()));
        };
    }
```

```
    @Override
    public DataFetcher<CompletableFuture<List<SomeObject>>> getSomething() {

        return env -> {

            return cluster.getClusterIdFromClientId("232")
                    .flatMap(clusterIdAndClientNameDTO -> repo.getFromStore(clusterIdAndClientNameDTO)
                            .collectList())
                    .toFuture();
        };
    }
```

However I dont see anything in the logs. It works for controller level call. When I use it in the service, it doesnt capture context, ie: REQUEST_ID is empty

Any ideas?

Comment: in your code snippets above, I don't see where the method `getSomething` is invoked. Without knowing how that is invoked limits how we can help. Can you update the code snippets to be a bit more reflective of your usage?

Comment: it will also be beneficial if you could provide a sample of the logs you see when invoking this endpoint

Comment: Have you considered using Spring Cloud Sleuth instead of managing this on your own?

Comment: @JoãoDias this is just for logging purposes not for full fledge tracing.

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen added more code. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen essentially i want to propogate the request id. Also have contextual logging, ie: want it to show in every log line.

Comment: it is common to invoke your `contextWrite` methods at the bottom of your reactive chain as it is done at subscription time which essentially is applied from the bottom to the top of your chain. Try moving `contextWrite` to the end.

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen i have dont that. But unable to capture `requestid` in the context for subsequents streams.

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen please see updated code. moved it to end but unable to capture the var in context in the sub streams.